# Implementing NSRunLoop

Tags: iphone, nstimer

Ok, I've read the articles about why it's a better idea to use an NSRunLoop instead of an NSTimer call to run a game loop and maintain a nice frame rate.

But what I haven't seen in any of the discussions is where to create the NSRunLoop.

Should that be put at the end of didFinishLoading?

Comment: Would you mind adding a link to those articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The run loop is automatically generated for you when you invoke `NSApplicationMain`. You can access the runloop with either of the following methods:

```
runloop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];
runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
```

---

The code in the forum you linked to looks like this:

```
// Yield to system calls (touches, etc.) for one ms.
while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0.002, NO) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource);
```

The documentation on `CFRunLoopRunInMode`:

> ```
> SInt32 CFRunLoopRunInMode (   
>     CFStringRef mode,
>     CFTimeInterval seconds,
>     Boolean returnAfterSourceHandled
> );
> ```
>
> Runs the current thread’s CFRunLoop
>   object in a particular mode.
>
> ### Parameters
>
> #### mode
>
> The run loop mode to
>   run. …
>
> #### seconds
>
> The length of time to run the
>   run loop. …
>
> #### returnAfterSourceHandled
>
> A flag
>   indicating whether the run loop should
>   exit after processing one source. …

This means that `CFRunLoopRunInMode` gets the current threads run loop and processes all waiting inputs. (Like touches…).

`while(… == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource)` ensures that all events are processed.

Just use the code as it is, this is working.

Comment: Currently my game invokes an NSTimer to fire off at the equivalent of 30fps.  But NSTimer is pretty innacurate for doing that kind of timing.  People mention creating a NSRunLoop to drive the app as mentioned on this thread here....

http://www.idevgames.com/forum/showthread.php?t=17058

But I don't understand how they are creating the NSRunLoop

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, NSRunLoop is an

> ***Event-Driven-Mode***

This OpenSource Project

> https://github.com/wuyunfeng/LightWeightRunLoop

In addition to implementing NSRunLoop using ***IO Multiplexing***, some Runloop-Relative Fundation API such as ***perform selector***(or delay some times) on other thread , ***Timer***, ***URLConnection*** etc